# Unicode development in MATLAB GUI on Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, matlab, user-interface, unicode

Can anyone please direct me in the Unicode development of MATLAB GUI over Windows and Linux platforms? My problem is the erroneous display of Unicode (French) characters in GUI and `*.m` files.

Once I keep the development to one platform (e.g. Windows) and do all my programming in Windows all Unicode text in GUIs and `*.m` files is displayed correctly. But as soon as I switch to Linux all Unicode characters present on Windows turn into squares. The same happens in the opposite direction (Linux --> Windows). For the development I use standard MATLAB editor.

Contents of my Windows `\Documents\MATLAB\startup.m` file are:

```
feature('DefaultCharacterSet', 'ISO-8859-1');
```

Minimal example, MATLAB function (`unicodeTest.m`) popping up a GUI warning message in French.

When opened in MATLAB 2011b, 32-bit on Linux, MATLAB editor:

```
function unicodeTest()

% S'il vous plaît sélectionner un autre fichier *.mat ou *.arr
warndlg('S''il vous plaît sélectionner un autre fichier *.mat ou *.arr.', ...
        'Avertissement');

end
```

When opened in MATLAB 2011a, 32-bit on Windows XP, MATLAB editor:

[image: Screenshot of MATLAB editor on Windows XP]

Comment: Please provide example code which allows to reproduce the issue.

Comment: IIRC MATLAB and Unicode don't mix well